# How to remove connecting area in fill_between() using Python and MatPlot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am graphing +-2 standard deviations from the mean on my graph (the green points). However, I would rather have straight vertical lines on top of each x-mean, because currently there is a connecting shade area between states that is misleading. How can I do this? I've tried everything and can't figure it out. Thanks in advance. (Since I'm new to Stack Overflow I can't post an image of my graph unfortunately.)

```
plt.scatter(x= joined.index.values, y = joined.poll_mean, color = "g")
plt.scatter(x= joined.index.values, y = joined.spread,color = joined.color)      
plt.fill_between(joined.index,(joined.poll_mean + 2*joined.poll_std).values, (joined.poll_mean - 2*joined.poll_std).values, color='g', alpha = .3)
plt.xticks(joined.index.values, joined.state.values, rotation='vertical')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do error bars? There is a matplotlib package for that.

An example piece of code to do this (from [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.5)
y = np.exp(-x)

# example variable error bar values
yerr = 0.1 + 0.2*np.sqrt(x)
xerr = 0.1 + yerr

# First illustrate basic pyplot interface, using defaults where possible.
plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=0.2, yerr=0.4)
plt.title("Simplest errorbars, 0.2 in x, 0.4 in y")
```

Also as a tip, for people to better help you, provide code that can reproduce your problem in full.